# No source code is available for type <xyz>; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Tags: eclipse, maven, gwt

I'm trying to add a [dependency](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-cal/) to my GWT project. The problem is that I am getting the following error:

```
[INFO] --- gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-beta-2:codeserver (default-cli) @ mahlzeit-web ---
[INFO] Turning off precompile in incremental mode.
[INFO] Super Dev Mode starting up
[INFO]    workDir: E:\java\mahlzeit-web\mahlzeit-web\target\gwt\codeserver
[INFO]    Loading Java files in com.mahlzeit.web.App.
[INFO]    Tracing compile failure path for type 'com.mahlzeit.web.GoogleCalendarPanel'
[INFO]       [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/E:/java/mahlzeit-web/mahlzeit-web/mahlzeit-web-client/src/main/java/com/mahlzeit/web/GoogleCalendarPanel.java'
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 54: No source code is available for type com.bradrydzewski.gwt.calendar.client.Calendar; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 161: No source code is available for type com.bradrydzewski.gwt.calendar.client.event.DeleteHandler<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
[INFO]          [ERROR] Line 162: No source code is available for type com.bradrydzewski.gwt.calendar.client.event.DeleteEvent<T>; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

I know I would have to add something like `<source ...>` to my `App.gwt.xml` file but that is *generated*. I am using the [gwt-maven-archetypes](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes) in Eclipse.

How can I add this dependency s.t. the GWT Compiler finds the sources in the library `.jar` file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the appropriate `<inherits/>` to your `src/main/module.gwt.xml`.

The plugin will only generate those inherits for JARs that contain a `META-INF/gwt/mainModule` (if that's what you mean by "that is generated"), i.e. almost none of them.

Comment: What Thomas said. I used gwt-cal that way.